# Passing a variable data in all controllers in codeigniter

Tags: json, codeigniter, session

Iam developing a website using codeigniter.I want to pass a particular data to all the controller.I searched and find it can be done by session like below.

```html
$var = $this->session->userdata('passingdata');
```

But this data loses when history is cleared and when session expires.

Is there any other way to pass variable to all controllers.

Comment: you can also create a custom helper function in application/helper folder and can access everywhere

Comment: Did you set the session save path don't leave it NULL on config.php

Comment: data values are dynamic or static??

Comment: dynamic @ Vishnu Bhadoriya

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this
 - create MY_Controller in application/core. it looks like

```
Class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('HomeModel');
    $this->global_data['settings']= $this->HomeModel->getSettings();
}

function display_view($view, $local_data = array()) {
    $data = array_merge($this->global_data, $local_data);
    return $this->load->view($view, $data);
}}
```

then extend this controller in your all controller

your functions in your controller like

```
 Class Home extends MY_Controller {
 public function index() {
    $data['title'] = 'test';       
    $this->display_view('home', $data);

}
```

}